# Naïve Bayes Classifier for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, machine-learning

Does anyone know if there is a library for the iPhone that includes a Naïve Bayes Classifier?

Answer (score 2):

I also needed Naive Bayes implementation but in Ruby. Turns out that different implementations are tailored for specific task and may not be easily adapted to what you may need. In the end it was simpler for me to write my own implementation with the added benefit of understanding all the different subtleties of how it actually works.

YMMV, but if you interested in some resources to get started, I've detailed my experience 
http://arubyguy.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/bayes-classification-update/

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Wikipedia page for Naive Bayes classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier), there are a few libraries that compile for Mac OS. You may have to rejigger them to get them building in Xcode for iPhone, but it's a start:

- [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)
- [IMSL Numerical Libraries](http://www.vni.com/products/imsl/)
- [Orange](http://www.ailab.si/orange/)
- [ifile](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jrennie/ifile/)